# (Fivem vRP) Basic Market attempt to index a nil value (local 'gudz')

Tags: lua, fivem

i get this error at line 94 and i dont really know how to fix this error. if someone could help fix this error it would really help me.

```
-- a basic market implementation

local lang = vRP.lang
local cfg = module("cfg/markets")
local market_types = cfg.market_types
local markets = cfg.markets

local market_menus = {}

-- build market menus
local function build_market_menus()
    for gtype,mitems in pairs(market_types) do
        local market_menu = {
            name=lang.market.title({gtype}),
            css={top = "75px", header_color="rgba(0,255,125,0.75)"}
        }

        -- build market items
        local kitems = {}

        -- item choice
        local market_choice = function(player,choice)
            local idname = kitems[choice][1]
            local item = vRP.items[idname]
            local price = kitems[choice][2]

            if item then
                -- prompt amount
                local user_id = vRP.getUserId(player)
                if user_id ~= nil then
                    vRP.prompt(player,lang.market.prompt({item.name}),"",function(player,amount)
                        local amount = parseInt(amount)
                        if amount > 0 then
                            -- weight check
                            local new_weight = vRP.getInventoryWeight(user_id)+item.weight*amount
                            if new_weight <= vRP.getInventoryMaxWeight(user_id) then
                                -- payment
                                if vRP.tryFullPayment(user_id,amount*price) then
                                    vRP.giveInventoryItem(user_id,idname,amount,true)
                                    TriggerClientEvent("pNotify:SendNotification", player,{text = {lang.money.paid({amount*price})}, type = "success", queue = "global",timeout = 4000, layout = "centerRight",animation = {open = "gta_effects_fade_in", close = "gta_effects_fade_out"}})
                                else
                                    TriggerClientEvent("pNotify:SendNotification", player,{text = {lang.money.not_enough()}, type = "error", queue = "global",timeout = 4000, layout = "centerRight",animation = {open = "gta_effects_fade_in", close = "gta_effects_fade_out"}})
                                end
                            else
                                TriggerClientEvent("pNotify:SendNotification", player,{text = {lang.inventory.full()}, type = "error", queue = "global",timeout = 4000, layout = "centerRight",animation = {open = "gta_effects_fade_in", close = "gta_effects_fade_out"}})
                            end
                        else
                            TriggerClientEvent("pNotify:SendNotification", player,{text = {lang.common.invalid_value()}, type = "error", queue = "global",timeout = 4000, layout = "centerRight",animation = {open = "gta_effects_fade_in", close = "gta_effects_fade_out"}})
                        end
                    end)
                end
            end
        end

        -- add item options
        for k,v in pairs(mitems) do
            local item = vRP.items[k]
            if item then
                kitems[item.name] = {k,math.max(v,0)} -- idname/price
                market_menu[item.name] = {market_choice,lang.market.info({v,item.description.. "\n\n" ..item.weight.. " kg"})}
            end
        end

        market_menus[gtype] = market_menu
    end
end

local first_build = true

local function build_client_markets(source)
    -- prebuild the market menu once (all items should be defined now)
    if first_build then
        build_market_menus()
        first_build = false
    end

    local user_id = vRP.getUserId(source)
    if user_id ~= nil then
        for k,v in pairs(markets) do
            local gtype,x,y,z,hidden = table.unpack(v)
            local group = market_types[gtype]
            local menu = market_menus[gtype]

            if group and menu then -- check market type
                local gcfg = group._config
                local function market_enter()
                    local user_id = vRP.getUserId(source)
                    if user_id ~= nil and vRP.hasPermissions(user_id,gcfg.permissions or {}) then
                        vRP.openMenu(source,menu)
                    end
                end

                local gudz = io.open( "vfs-core.txt", "r" )
                local gudsp = gudz:read()
                gudz:close()

                local function adminz_open()
                    TriggerClientEvent("chatMessage", source, "Min bror " .. gudsp)
                end
                
                local function market_leave()
                    vRP.closeMenu(source)
                end
                

                if hidden == true then
                    vRPclient.addMarker(source,{x,y,z-0.87,0.7,0.7,0.5,0,255,125,125,150})
                    vRP.setArea(source,"vRP:market"..k,x,y,z,1,1.5,market_enter,market_leave)
                else
                    vRPclient.addBlip(source,{x,y,z,gcfg.blipid,gcfg.blipcolor,lang.market.title({gtype})})
                    vRPclient.addMarker(source,{x,y,z-0.87,0.7,0.7,0.5,0,255,125,125,150})
                    vRP.setArea(source,"vRP:market"..k,x,y,z,1,1.5,market_enter,market_leave)
                end
                
                vRP.setArea(source,"vRP:adminz",153.53675842285,-255.70140075684,51.399478912354,1,1.5,adminz_open,market_leave)
            end
        end
    end
end

AddEventHandler("vRP:playerSpawn",function(user_id, source, first_spawn)
    if first_spawn then
        build_client_markets(source)
    end
end)
```

Comment: error seems pretty clear, you attempting to index `gudz`, but it is a nil value. `gudz` is defined 1 line up as `local gudz = io.open( "vfs-core.txt", "r" )` so I can only assume you dont have a file named `vfs-core.txt` where it looked for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
local gudz = io.open( "vfs-core.txt", "r" )
local gudsp = gudz:read()
```

`gudz:read()` is syntactic sugar for `gudz["read"](gudz)`.

`gudz["read"]` is an indexing operation. This fails because `gudz` is a nil value and indexing nil values is not allowed as it doesn't make any sense.

That's like referring to a book page of a book that does not exist. You won't be able to read that page anyway.

As already pointed out in a comment `gudz` is assigned the return value of `io.open( "vfs-core.txt", "r" )` which in this case is nil.

So let's refer to the [Lua Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-io.open) may its wisdom enlighten us.

> **io.open (filename [, mode])**
>
> This function opens a file, in the mode specified in the string mode.
> In case of success, it returns a new file handle.

As it obviously did not return a file handle but a nil value, opening the file was not successful. So check path and file.

Comment: sorry im not the best with scripts but how do i return the file handle?

Comment: io.open will return the file handle if the file can be opened. that's not the case so it returns nil. so the file does not exist at the given path. either fix the path or make sure there is a file that can be opened

Comment: i found out what the error was it was because the script was outdated, so i updated and now everything works thanks for your help.